# Laravel eloquent, select model with relationship in a single query

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

Let's say we have many-to-many relationship for models Car and Driver:

```
class Car extends Model {...}

class Connection extends Model
{
    public function car()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('app\Car');
    }

    public function driver()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Driver');
    }
}

class Driver extends Model {...}
```

Now I'd like to query for Cars which can be driven by John. With QueryBuilder this is quite simple:

```
 $query = DB::table('cars')
        ->join('connections', 'cars.id', '=', 'connections.car_id')
        ->join('drivers', 'connection.driver_id', '=', 'drivers.id')
        ->where('drivers.name', 'like', 'John')->select('cars.*')->get();
```

This will generate a single SQL query which is more or less exactly would I'd expect.

The rest of the application uses Eloquent for DB querying and so I'd like to rewrite this part with Eloquent. I gave it multiple tries but I can't generate a single query with plain JOINs (not subqueries). Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use whereHas eloquent function to get Cars which can be driven by John

```
$cars = Car::whereHas('drivers',function($query) use ($driver_name){
       $query->where('name','like','%'.$driver_name.'%');
})->get();
```

for models you can use which @Idob write to his answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `belongsToMany` relationship and delete your `Connection` model.

Change your models to be:

```
class Car extends Model
{
    public function drivers()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Driver::class, 'connection');
    }
}

class Driver extends Model
{
    public function cars()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Car::class, 'connection');
    }
}
```

And query the driver's cars by:

```
$drivers = Driver::with('cars')
    ->where('name', 'like', 'John')
    ->get();

foreach ($drivers as $driver) {
    $cars = $driver->cars;
}
```

Another small optimization is to follow Laravel's conventions for table naming and call the `connection` table as `car_driver` - than you would be able to remove the second parameter from the `belongsToMany` mathod.

Comment: I can't use belongsToMany because my "Connection" model is slightly more complex than the one from the above example. I checked your code and it works but it's inefficient; Laravel showed two queries that were executed. Also, in your example you call first() but if I'll take all drivers (named John) then the generated query will become even less efficient due to "where id in (.....)"

Comment: I've updated to query to support multiple drivers, check it out. For the inefficiency that you mentioned - that's true, that's two queried instead of one. In general ORM is less efficient than writing your own queries but the benefits you get worth it. So, unless that's a page with tens of millions of hits per day - I would stick with the ORM & Eloquent.

Comment: I see, so as a conclusion: there is literally no way to have one and only one query. Yes?

Comment: Since each Eloquent model serves as a query builder, you can call the `Car` class instead of `DB` and remove the `table('cars')`, but it's the same query builder - so it doesn't matter.